# Paths.get()... in other words, If you follow the trail you get lost

Tags: java, interface, path, abstract

In my code I have this instruction:

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("c:\\java\\");
```

Being Path just an interface, I was wondering what get() was doing inside. So I opened the source code in Path.class and here's what I found:

```
public static Path get(String first, String... more) {
    return FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(first, more);
}
```

As you can see there is a getPath() that return a Path. So I opened FileSystem.class to see the getPath and here's what I found this time... an abstract method:

```
public abstract Path getPath(String first, String... more);
```

How is it possible? This code seems to do nothing and there is also an abstract method so I can't see how it's run. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Are you differentiating between `Path` and `Paths`? Or `FileSystem` and `FileSystems`?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `FileSystems.getDefault()` you obtain an implementation of FileSystem (OS dependant), which have its own implementation of getPath, to return its own  implementation of Path interface.

Comment: +1. Nitpicking: it is FileSystems.getDefault(), with **s** at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you looked at wrong place for implmentation. You looked at `getPath` of `FileSystem` class. Note that `FileSystem` itself is an abstract class wherein `getPath` is declared as an abstract method, as you noticed. This is because, there must be a file system provider which implements the specific mechanisms of it by extending `FileSystem` class. For instance, when you try to access file system on Unix or Windows, there's a default file system provider which handles all your requests like, file creation, direcotry/folder listing etc... The default file system manages files on HDD. Likewise, there could be another file system which might manage files in memory like [Google's Jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs).

Secondly, as `get` method of `Paths` returns a `Path` object by invoking `FileSystems.getDefault()`, you should have first digged into `getDefault` method of `FileSystems`. This would have led you to a default file system provider. As mentioned above, OSs like Unix and Windows have a default file system provider and are part of respective JDK/JRE. For instance, Oracle's JDK has a default one.